# JavaScript object exist, but can't access it

Tags: javascript

I'm tyring to find out how some website works. In it's JS codes there is a 'Commander' object that is used many times in scripts within webpages:

```
parent.Commander.SetTime();
parent.Commander.GetData();
etc...
```

and they work, i know because the SetTime() already sets the time for the pages i view within the website and other methods also are doing their jobs.
but when i try to access the Commander object i can't.(parent.Commander returns 'undefined' when i try to access it in debug console)
Plus, i can't find where 'Commander' is defined.
The webpage looks like this:
There is a frameset, and one of it's frames' name is 'Commander'.

```
...
<FRAME noResize src="/_Templates/Commander.htm" name=Commander scrolling=no>
...
```

'Commander.htm' loads 'Commander.js'.

```
...
<SCRIPT language=javascript src="/_Scripts/Commander.js"></SCRIPT>
...
```

'Commander.js' consist of function definitions

```
function SetTime(){
...
}
...
```

but the commander object is not defined anywhere. i'm expecting something like this:

```
function Commander()
{
SetTime()
...
}
```

OR

```
Commander = new Object();
Commander.SetTime=function();
```

so i want to know how i can access Commander's methods.
(if my question is unclear, please ask me to explain more. thank you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parent.Commander` refers to the frame's content window, so `parent.Commander.SetTime()` would bsically be referring to the global function `SetTime()` defined within the `Commander` frame.

Comment: so, document.parentWindow.parent.parent.Commander.RetAut(); means we are 3 levels in Frames?

Comment: I have no idea. I'd just use `top` personally.

Comment: i hate frames, just imagine, a frameset, in another frameset, in another frameset, all in an iframe. and each frameset has two other frames. and i have to find out why document.parentWindow.parent.parent.Commander.RetAut() doesn't work!!!

Comment: Who defined that bollocks?